# i gad an error in my simple app says Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, cubit

I had an error when I am trying to switch between dark mode and light mode using Shared Preferences I need to insert a bool like false as an example and I need when restart the application the Boolean's value remain the same
[image]

this is the page I need to change the Theme mode

this is the file that I made the bool inside

```
void main() async {
  // since the main is async and await you have to put this method to make sure that the await methods is done and then eunning the app
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  DioHelper.init(); // this one here is to create the dio object
  await CacheHelper.init(); // this one here is to create the SP object
  bool? isDark = CacheHelper.getBoolian(key: 'isDark');
  runApp(MyApp(isDark!));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isDark;

  const MyApp(this.isDark, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => AppCubit()
        ..changeAppMode(
          fromShared: isDark,
        ),
      child: BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
        listener: (context, state) {},
        builder: (context, state)
```

I am using cubit so this is my method for change the mode

```
bool isaDarkMode = true;

  void changeAppMode({bool? fromShared}) {
    if (fromShared != null) {
      isaDarkMode = fromShared;
      emit(AppChangeMoadeState());
    } else {
      isaDarkMode = !isaDarkMode;
    }
    // here iam inserting a data into the SP method to save it there
    CacheHelper.putBoolian(key: ' isaDarMode', value: isaDarkMode)
        .then((value) {
      emit(AppChangeMoadeState());
      print('Emit and INSERTING done successfully');
    });
  }
}
```

this is the Shared preference method

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

// here Iam creating the method of Shared Prefrences
class CacheHelper {
  static SharedPreferences? sharedPreferences;

  //This method is to define the shared prefrence
  static init() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  // this one is for insert a data into the SP(SharedPrefrences)
  static Future<bool> putBoolian({
    required String key,
    required bool value,
  }) async {
    return await sharedPreferences!.setBool(key, value);
  }

  // this one is for get a data into the SP
  static bool? getBoolian({
    required String key,
  }) {
    return sharedPreferences!.getBool(key);
  }
}
```

Comment: isDark != isaDarMode

Comment: he did not see isaDarkmode

Answer (score 0):

Try with default value

```dart
bool? isDark = CacheHelper.getBoolian(key: 'isDark');
runApp(MyApp(isDark??false));
```

Comment: this one did not work too

Comment: Can you include widget with cubit

Comment: What do you mean??

Comment: can you include full widget & cubit